# Problemas al mostrar en un JTable una imagen obtenida de una base de datos en mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Buen dia, a la hora de ejecutar el programa se supone que deberia mostrarse la imagen en el JTable pero en su lugar sale el siguiente texto, en intentado haciendo el cambio de mas tamaño en my.ini pero no me deja, adjunto fotos, el error y mi código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Texto que sale en donde deberia ir la imagen:
javax.swing.JLabel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=javax.swing.ImageIcon@773edda8,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=CENTER,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]

Código:

```
public class TablaCredenciales {
    Credenciales cre = null;
    public void visualizar_credenciales(JTable tabla){
        tabla.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new Render());
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
                return false;
            }
        };
        dtm.addColumn("Id");
        dtm.addColumn("Nombre");
        dtm.addColumn("Apellido Paterno");
        dtm.addColumn("Apellido Materno");
        dtm.addColumn("Fecha de Nacimiento");
        dtm.addColumn("Equipo");
        dtm.addColumn("Categoria");
        dtm.addColumn("Foto");
        dtm.addColumn("Modificar");
        dtm.addColumn("Eliminar");
        JButton btn_modificar = new JButton("Modificar");
        btn_modificar.setName("m");
        JButton btn_eliminar = new JButton("Eliminar");
        btn_eliminar.setName("e");
        cre = new Credenciales();
        FuncionesCredenciales fc = new FuncionesCredenciales();
        ArrayList<FuncionesCredenciales> list = cre.ListarCredenciales();
        if(list.size() > 0){
            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
                Object fila[] = new Object[10];
                fc = list.get(i);
                fila[0] = fc.getId();
                fila[1] = fc.getNombreJugador();
                fila[2] = fc.getApellidoPaterno();
                fila[3] = fc.getApellidoMaterno();
                fila[4] = fc.getFechaNacimiento();
                fila[5] = fc.getEquipo();
                fila[6] = fc.getCategoria();
                try{
                    byte[] bi = fc.getFotoJugador();
                    BufferedImage image = null;
                    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bi);
                    image = ImageIO.read(in);
                    ImageIcon imgi = new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(60, 60, 0));
                    fila[7] = new JLabel(imgi);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, imgi);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    fila[7] = new JLabel("Sin foto");
                }
                fila[8] = btn_modificar;
                fila[9] = btn_eliminar;
                dtm.addRow(fila);
            }
            tabla.setModel(dtm);
            tabla.setRowHeight(60);
        }
    }   
}

public class Credenciales {
public ArrayList <FuncionesCredenciales> ListarCredenciales(){
    ArrayList<FuncionesCredenciales> credenciales = new ArrayList<FuncionesCredenciales>();
    Conexion conn = new Conexion();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM credencialjugador";
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        ps = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            FuncionesCredenciales fc = new FuncionesCredenciales();
            fc.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            fc.setNombreJugador(rs.getString(2));
            fc.setApellidoPaterno(rs.getString(3));
            fc.setApellidoMaterno(rs.getString(4));
            fc.setFechaNacimiento(rs.getString(5));
            fc.setEquipo(rs.getInt(6));
            fc.setCategoria(rs.getInt(7));
            fc.setFotoJugador(rs.getBytes(8));
            credenciales.add(fc);
        }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception ex){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            ps.close();
            rs.close();
            conn.desconectar();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    return credenciales;
}
public void AgregarCredencial(FuncionesCredenciales fc){
    Conexion conn = new Conexion();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO credencialjugador (nombreJugador, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, fechaNacimiento, equipo, categoria, fotoJugador) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        ps = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, fc.getNombreJugador());
        ps.setString(2, fc.getApellidoPaterno());
        ps.setString(3, fc.getApellidoMaterno());
        ps.setString(4, fc.getFechaNacimiento());
        ps.setInt(5, fc.getEquipo());
        ps.setInt(6, fc.getCategoria());
        ps.setBytes(7, fc.getFotoJugador());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            ps.close();
            conn.desconectar();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
public void ModificarEquipo(FuncionesCredenciales fc){
    Conexion conn = new Conexion();
    String sql = "UPDATE credencialjugador SET nombreJugador = ?, apellidoPaterno = ?, apellidoMaterno = ?, fechaNacimiento = ?, equipo = ?, categoria = ?, fotoJugador = ?  WHERE id = ?;";
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        ps = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, fc.getNombreJugador());
        ps.setString(2, fc.getApellidoPaterno());
        ps.setString(3, fc.getApellidoMaterno());
        ps.setString(4, fc.getFechaNacimiento());
        ps.setInt(5, fc.getEquipo());
        ps.setInt(6, fc.getCategoria());
        ps.setBytes(7, fc.getFotoJugador());
        ps.setInt(8, fc.getId());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            ps.close();
            conn.desconectar();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
public void EliminarEquipo(FuncionesCredenciales fc){
    Conexion conn = new Conexion();
    String sql = "DELETE FROM credencialjugador WHERE id = ?;";
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        ps = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, fc.getId());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            ps.close();
            conn.desconectar();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: El `CellRenderer` que se encarga de renderizar el contenido de cada celda de una `JTable` por defecto renderiza texto, que es lo más normal que quieras meter en una tabla, obviamente. Así que cuando le pasas un objeto (en tu caso, un JLabel, parece), lo que hace es imprimirte la representación de ese objeto como String. Lo que necesitas es indicarle a la table que en esa casilla no hay un String, si no un icono, de hecho, lo que se hace es [sobreescribir el método getColumnClass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947154/14083367) y eso permite que la tabla renderice las cosas adecuadamente :)

Comment: Y como le hago en el codigo? no entiendo bien como adaptarlo